# Deleting column with the least sum in dataframes dynamically in R

Tags: r, dataframe

In a data frame, I am trying to delete the column whose sum is the least. I want it to be dynamic since I want to use it in a function

E.g

```
     a      b   c
1   434     0   45
2   5452    1   456
3   42342   0   26
4   542     1   15
5   542     1   323
6   413     0   45
```

I want to remove the 2nd column [i.e. column b] since its sum is the least, but this I want it to be done dynamically since I have to use it as a part of a function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can try with `colSums` with `which.min` to create the index of the minimum column sum and remove that column.

```
df1[-which.min(colSums(df1))]
```

---

Or another option is `Filter`

```
mn <- min(sapply(df1, sum))
Filter(function(x) sum(x) != mn, df1)
```

Comment: I am sorry.... I think I did it by mistake... I wanted to upvote.... now that I am trying to upvote, but I am unable to do it.....
Also, the question has been downvoted - twice

Comment: Thanx a ton for your help